# Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azure-storage

I was recieving the following error message when trying to run a TimerTrigger based Azure Function:

```
Exception while executing function: Functions.FooFunction Exception binding parameter 'myTimer' Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor
```

Important to note that the Azure Function runs locally. To try to resolve the issue I added the following setting to my project 'local.settings.json' file:

```
"AzureWebJobsStorage": "<connection_string>",
```

After now receiving the following error:

```
The listener for function 'Functions.FooFunction' was unable to start. Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor
```

I am very to new to Azure and developing for Azure Functions so I am sure I am not understanding the Storage account connection correctly? I am sure I have a Storage account enabled and that the connection string is correct. I am not sure what else needs to be configured in the storage account and / or azure function app?

Thanks in advance for your help!

EDIT:

Stock VS Azure Function Code:

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace AzureFunctionTest
{
    public class Function1
    {
        private readonly ILogger _logger;

        public Function1(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            _logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Function1>();
        }

        [Function("Function1")]
        public void Run([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *")] MyInfo myTimer)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"C# Timer trigger function executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
            _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
        }
    }

    public class MyInfo
    {
        public MyScheduleStatus ScheduleStatus { get; set; }

        public bool IsPastDue { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyScheduleStatus
    {
        public DateTime Last { get; set; }

        public DateTime Next { get; set; }

        public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Project config:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <DockerFastModeProjectMountDirectory>/home/site/wwwroot</DockerFastModeProjectMountDirectory>
    <DockerDefaultTargetOS>Linux</DockerDefaultTargetOS>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.4" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Update="host.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
    <None Update="local.settings.json">
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
      <CopyToPublishDirectory>Never</CopyToPublishDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <Using Include="System.Threading.ExecutionContext" Alias="ExecutionContext" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Works running locally:

[image]

Azure App Insights error when trying to run function app in Azure:

```
The listener for function 'Functions.Function1' was unable to start. Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor
```

Call stack:

```
Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListenerException:
System.InvalidOperationException:
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor.get_ContainerClient (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:83)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor+<GetStatusBlobClient>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:155)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.StorageScheduleMonitor+<GetStatusAsync>d__11.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Storage\StorageScheduleMonitor.cs:94)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Timers.Listeners.TimerListener+<StartAsync>d__32.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions, Version=5.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: C:\azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions\src\WebJobs.Extensions\Extensions\Timers\Listener\TimerListener.cs:105)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.SingletonListener+<StartAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Singleton\SingletonListener.cs:70)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult (System.Private.CoreLib, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Listeners.FunctionListener+<StartAsync>d__13.MoveNext (Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.39.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35: D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Listeners\FunctionListener.cs:68)
```

Comment: Provide code which you are working

Comment: @RithwikBojja Edited with some code and results showing working locally and error when trying to run in Azure. Note: In the above example I am just trying to run the stock code when you create a new Azure Function in Visual Studio 2022. Given that the stock code is throwing same error as my real code (cannot post here in full due to security) I do not believe issue has anything to with code. Seems to be related to my Azure Function app setup in Azure but not sure what to look for there? Also runs locally which would seem to rule out code. Since runs locally using Azurite for storage.

Comment: @seanrco, Is it .NET 6 isolated function?

Comment: @Pravallika KV .NET 7 isolated function. Added proj config to original post.

Comment: Try adding the setting `"AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"` in local.settings.json. and check by deleting the package `<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets" Version="1.19.4" />`

Comment: @PravallikaKV "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true" was already in place in local.settings.json. I uninstalled the' Microsoft.VisualStudio.Azure.Containers.Tools.Targets' package per your notes. Confirmed still runs locally. However, still receiving errors in Azure: 

Exception while executing function: Functions.Function1 Exception binding parameter 'myTimer' Could not create BlobContainerClient for ScheduleMonitor

Comment: Try creating a new function app, disable docker while creating the function in vs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- It seems like there is an issue with the connection to the storage account.
- Try with any other storage account's connection string in the `"AzureWebJobsStorage":"storage_connection_string>"`.

***If nothing works, try creating a new function app and storage account and deploy your function and check the issue still persists.***

I reproduced the same in my environment, it worked without any issues:

**Steps followed:**

- Created `.NET 7 isolated Timer Trigger Azure function` and working fine locally.

[image]

**local.settings.json:**

```json
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
    "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet-isolated"
    }
}
```

**.csproj:**

```xml
 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
   <AzureFunctionsVersion>v4</AzureFunctionsVersion>
   <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
   <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
   <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
 </PropertyGroup>
 <ItemGroup>
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker" Version="1.19.0" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Extensions.Timer" Version="4.0.1" />
   <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Sdk" Version="1.14.0" />
 </ItemGroup>
```

- Created `.NET 7 Isolated Azure Function App` and deployed the function to that app and could run it successfully as shown below:

[image]

**Application Insights:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I am not sure what was wrong with my original storage account, but I created a new azure function and azure storage account, and it is working now. I also used the Visual Studio publishing profile to set the storage and app insights service decencies. Most importantly if anyone runs across similar issues check into your azure configuration and most likely not code related.